# Broken / Missing Vertical Line on Table

Tags: tables, booktabs, vertical

I've been trying to recreate this table, [image]

so far i manage to write,

```
\begin{table*}[h!]
\caption{Bit error rates of different templates when using the same deep-learning based extraction method}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc|cc} 
\toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Algorithms} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{JPEG (QF=50)} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Med-Filter $7\times7$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Gau-Filter $7\times7$} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{Gau-Noise $\sigma=0.01$} \\ \cmidrule {2-9}
     & Traditional & CNN & Traditional & CNN & Traditional & CNN & Traditional & CNN \\ \midrule
     Nakamura \textit{et al.} [12] & $35.99\%$ & $\mathbf{29.51\%}$ & $ 9.38\%$ & $\mathbf{8.39\%}$ & $0.00\%$ & $\mathbf{0.00\%}$ & $0.00\%$ & $\mathbf{0.00\%}$ \\ \midrule
     Primila \textit{et al.} [23] & $45.01\%$ & $\mathbf{38.35\%}$ & $ 38.76\%$ & $\mathbf{26.31\%}$ & $4.12\%$ & $\mathbf{1.19\%}$ & $24.34\%$ & $\mathbf{22.75\%}$ \\ \midrule
     Gugelmann \textit{et al.} [15] & $16.16\%$ & $\mathbf{15.76\%}$ & $ 15.63\%$ & $\mathbf{8.86\%}$ & $14.48\%$ & $\mathbf{3.93\%}$ & $\mathbf{13.01\%}$ & $16.41\%$ \\ \midrule
     Proposed & $17.63\%$ & $\mathbf{6.42\%}$ & $ 15.45\%$ & $\mathbf{1.18\%}$ & $12.98\%$ & $\mathbf{0.68\%}$ & $11.91\%$ & $\mathbf{3.37\%}$ \\ 
     \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table*}
```

but from that i'm missing these vertical lines,
[image]

how to fix this? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: `\multicolumn{2}{c|}` instead of `\multicolumn{2}{c}` adds the missing part of the vertical line back. Your table would however look a lot more professional if you would stick to the `booktabs` principle: No vertical rules in a table.

Comment: You already asked this question and receive three answers from which two of them solve problem of vertical lines. Please consider them in question and explain us, what is your new problem!